# ActionBarActivity & ActivityUnitTest - NameNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-testing, android-actionbar-compat

Ok...it is more likely to be my fault ;)

When I do:

```
public class XmlLifecycleTests extends ActivityUnitTestCase<Main> {
...
    (not in setUp)
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setPackage(APP_PACKAGE);
    intent.setClassName(APP_PACKAGE, ".gui.Main");
    startActivity(intent, null, null);
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{ar.android.app.gui/ar.android.app.gui.GLarmMain}
at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:282)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:119)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
at ar.android.app.gui.Main.onCreate(Main.java:78)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:158)
```

Note that my Main activity is defined under .gui while the main package in the manifest is one folder up, this is why I specified everything in the intent. But the thrown error seems to still get the wrong (Package,Class) name pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was indeed my fault...switching `startActivity` to:

`setActivity(launchActivity(pkg, actClass, null));`

Solved all my problems.

Comment: What happened to me was: I had an activity A in the working application. I had an activity B, that extended A in the junittest application. I was using an ActivityUnitTestCase to test activity B, but I had not added activity B to my manifest file in my junit testing application. Added it and PackageManager$NameNotFoundException gone.