# ActivityUnitTestCase throws NameNotFoundException with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, activityunittestcase

There appears to be a long outstanding issue with ActivityUnitTestCase whereby the use of a package for the target activity other than that defined in the manifest leads to a NameNotFoundException (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22737). There is a comment on the issue log suggesting that this does not prevent test execution - this is not what I have found when testing an ActionBarActivity.

The suggested workaround here ([ActionBarActivity & ActivityUnitTest - NameNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611539/actionbaractivity-activityunittest-namenotfoundexception)) using launchActivity() appears to preclude the use of a mock context/app. Does anyone know how to use a tiered package structure in the project under test and call startActivity() in AUTC without raising an exception?